# Get top 3 salaries columnwise department wise in employee table?

Tags: sql, select, join, subquery

There are 2 tables :-
The Employee table holds all employees.

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+  
| Id | Name  | Sa1ary | DepartmentId |   
+----+-------+--------+--------------+  
|  1 | Joe   |  70000 |            1 |  
|  2 | Henry |  80000 |            2 |  
|  3 | Sam   |  60000 |            2 |  
|  4 | Max   |  90000 |            3 |  
|  5 | Janet |  69000 |            4 |  
|  6 | Randy |  85000 |            1 |  
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

Department table is as follows:-

```
+----+------------+      
|DID |  DNAME     |   
+----+------------+  
|1   |  IT        |  
|2   |  ADMIN     |  
|3   |  HR        |  
|4   |  MARKETING |  
|5   |  SALES     |  
+----+------------+
```

output should be :-

```
+-----+--------+--------+------+------+  
|Dname| Best    |Seond best |  Worst |  
+-----+--------+--------+------+------+  
|IT   |  40000  |30000  |10000        |  
+-----+--------+--------+------+------+    
|ADMIN| 50000   |   |50000        |   
+-----+--------+--------+------+------+  
|HR   | 70000   |60000  |60000        |   
+-----+--------+--------+------+------+
```

we have to consider maximum,second maximum and 3 maximum salary from each department.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: The given output doesnt seem to be consistent with the given input tables. Could you please check? Also, what is the criteria of 'Best worst; column? 3rd best? if only one employee is present in a department. is the best and 'best worst' expected to be same in the output or the 'best worst' column is expected to be null? Please update the details is the question.

Comment: You can use mysql as the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(Id INT, Name VARCHAR(100), Salary INT, DepartmentId INT)
CREATE TABLE #Table2(DID INT, DNAME VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Table1(Id , Name , Salary , DepartmentId )
SELECT 1,'Joe',70000,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Henry',80000,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Sam',60000,2 UNION ALL  
SELECT 4,'Max',90000,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Janet',69000,4 UNION ALL  
SELECT 6,'Randy',85000,1 

INSERT INTO #Table2(DID , DNAME)
SELECT 1,'IT' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'ADMIN' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'HR' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'MARKETING' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'SALES'  

;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table1 WHERE e.salary <= salary AND  departmentID=e.departmentID) AS RowNo FROM #Table1 e
)
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
SELECT DNAME,salary,CASE WHEN RowNo = 1 THEN 'Best' WHEN RowNo  = 2 THEN 'Seond' WHEN RowNo = 3 THEN 'Best Worst' END RowNo
 FROM CTE 
 JOIN #Table2 ON DID = DepartmentId
 WHERE RowNo <= 3
 )A
PIVOT
(
  MAX(salary) FOR RowNo IN ([Best],[Seond],[Best Worst])
) PVT
```

Comment: ["Answers to questions tagged with `sql` should use ISO/IEC standard SQL."](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server you can use [SQL Row_Number function with Partition By](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) clause to rank rows according to a value in a group based on a selected column

I also used CTE expression and GROUP By operator

```
;with cte as (
select 
    Dname, Sa1ary, ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By d.DId Order By Sa1ary desc) rn
from employee e
inner join department d on e.DepartmentId = d.DId
)
select
    dname,
    max(Best) Best,
    max(Seond) Seond,
    max("Best Worst") "Best Worst"
from (
select
    Dname,
    case when rn = 1 then Sa1ary else null end as Best,
    case when rn = 2 then Sa1ary else null end as Seond,
    case when rn = 3 then Sa1ary else null end as "Best Worst"
from cte
) t
group by dname
```

Please note that the results are not as you showed, there is a mistake there I guess.

[image]
Please test the above, I hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the solution..it really helped

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Pivot Query.

```
            select * from 
            (
            select DName,salary,Class from
            (
            select 
            *,
            case when RID='1' then 'Best'
            when RID='2' then 'second'
            when RID='3' then 'Best Worst'
            else
            NULL
            end as CLASS
            from (
            select DID,Dname,salary ,     
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION  BY Dname ,DID
            ORDER BY salary DESC  ) as RID
             from
             #Employee E inner join  #Department D on E.DepartmentId=d.DID
             )a
            where rid <4
            )b   
            ) as x
            pivot(
            max(salary) for class in ( [Best],[Second],[Best Worst]) 
            )
            as pivot1
```